# Prove using the definition of Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $B = X \cup Y$, and $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint compact intervals, then

$$m^*(B) = m^*(X) + m^*(Y)$$

(This is not always true for disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but it is for intervals)

I understand conceptually what is happening I think, but I can't express it mathematically.

I'm not very proficient at writing proofs, at least not to what is expected of me. I really want to learn, I'm just having to play catch-up this semester. I want to study the answer, not just have it solved for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: two disjoint compact intervals are "separated" by some distance, so you can assume that none of your open balls intersect both $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Does $m^*$ denote the Lebesgue outer-measure? And is this a homework problem?

Comment: @Thomas, yes it is, I just found out about the hw tag

Comment: This can be generalized to an arbitrary number of pairwise disjoint measurable sets. A hint: show that the LHS is both greater than or equal to and less than or equal to the right hand side.

Comment: @lyj Okay, that's what I was thinking, but I'm not really sure how to start with that method. My proof skills are currently very poor...

Comment: @lyj I'll try playing with it for a little while and put up any results

Comment: If you haven't had much experience with proofs, note that a very heavily used trick for proving $a = b$ is to show that $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a$. That might be useful here.